# How to connect flutter app in Genymotion via visual studio code

Tags: windows-10

I tried to connect flutter app in Genymotion i have using IDE as Visual Studio Code...Any one can guide me how to connect flutter app in Genymotion

If I run project means it showing like this:

$ flutter run
Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but after several hours I found a problem
The problem with this is that genymotion says it has a problem with platform-tools 28.0.2 and fixes this problem in the last update (3.0.2).

I first updated genymotion

I then handled the adb tools connection (sdk)

I reset the system and my problem was resolved

I hope that the problem will be resolved by this method